# opencv matchTemplate gives inconsistent results between computers

Tags: c++, opencv, gpu

I'm running the following code on two different computers, the first one has a Nvidia GPU Quadro FX 880M, and the second is Quadro FX 1000M (compiled in VS2010, opencv242,64bit; opencv was compiled from source).
the code I'm running is the following:

```
int n = 1000;  //number of iterations
int t = CV_TM_CCORR_NORMED; //correlation type




//reset GPU, print device info
cv::gpu::printCudaDeviceInfo(cv::gpu::getDevice());
cv::gpu::resetDevice(); 




//read big image
cv::Mat imgA = cv::imread("img.bmp"  ,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
//read small, template image
cv::Mat imgB = cv::imread("tmplt.bmp",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);




//upload images to GPU
cv::gpu::GpuMat imgA_GPU,imgB_GPU;
imgA_GPU.upload(imgA);
imgB_GPU.upload(imgB);





cv::gpu::GpuMat imgC_GPU; //correlation results, computer in GPU
cv::Mat         imgC_CPU; //correlation results, computer in CPU




//matchTemplate in GPU, print average time(mSec)
size_t t1 = clock();
for(int i = 0;i!=n;++i)
    cv::gpu::matchTemplate(imgA_GPU , imgB_GPU, imgC_GPU , t);

std::cout << "GPU: " <<
(double(clock())-t1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC*1000.0/n <<std::endl;





//matchTemplate in CPU, print average time(mSec)
size_t t2 = clock();
for(int i = 0;i!=n;++i)
    cv::     matchTemplate(imgA     , imgB    , imgC_CPU , t);

std::cout << "CPU: " <<
(double(clock())-t2)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC*1000.0/n <<std::endl;






//download GPU image to host
cv::Mat imgC_GPUhost;
imgC_GPU.download(imgC_GPUhost);




//convert images to 8U
imgC_CPU.convertTo(imgC_CPU,CV_8U,255);
imgC_GPUhost.convertTo(imgC_GPUhost,CV_8U,255);




//!!!!!! imgC_GPUhost should be equal to imgC_CPU
cv::Mat diff;
cv::absdiff(imgC_CPU,imgC_GPUhost,diff);
//expected: RESULTS DIFF: 0
std::cout << "RESULTS DIFF: " << cv::sum(diff).val[0] << std::endl;





cv::imwrite("cor2.bmp",imgC_CPU);
cv::imwrite("cor.bmp",imgC_GPUhost);
char s;
std::cin >> s;
```

there are two major things that puzzles me:

1. on the Quadro FX 880M this function DOES NOT WORK: the GPU output image (imgC_GPU) is all zeros - doesn't matter if input type(8U or 32F) or correlation method (ccor,ccoef,etc).
   On the other hand, in the Quadro FX 1000M I get consistent results between the CPU and GPU. how can it be, and what do I need to do to make it work on the Quadro FX 880M?
2. in template matching every pixel in the output image can be calculated independently from the other pixels - hence paralleling is easy, and GPU implementation suits perfectly. How is it possible, that even when looking at the average time (as in the code), the GPU performance are 3 times SLOWER than the CPU? it was verified on both computer, with no other process running in the background.

Ohad

Comment: The FX880M is a compute capability 1.x device, whereas the FX1000M is a compute capability 2.x device. Are you sure that you are using the correct compilation flags to ensure that there is code for the compute 1.x GPU?

Comment: I've compiled with CUDA_ARCH_BIN support of both compute capabilities (1.2 and 2.1), I'm not sure what is the difference between "generate ready to run binary code", and "generate ready to be compiled just-in-time code"...

Answer (score 0):

It's seems like the GPU version of matchTemplate was develop with simultaneous searchs of multiple templates in mind.  Indeed, with one image/one template, the CPU version seems faster.

http://answers.opencv.org/question/16061/opencv-matchtemplate-cuda-large-images-templates/